# Distinguishing Mandarin Characters vs Words

Tags: python, nlp

I am attempting to create a python program that can find the frequency of Mandarin characters and words in a text document. The problem I am facing is that many Mandarin words are just two or more words combined, for example: "you" is 你 and "hello" is 你好. Is there a way that my program can see 你好 and recognize that it isn't two words (you and good), rather one word (hello)?

Comment: You're probably going to need a natural language processing library that knows Mandarin.

Comment: is there no whitespace between the words?

Comment: No white spaces between words